# Calculating a date in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I am trying to calculate the date/time seven days and four hours in the future from an entered date and print it in a human readable format.

I have:

```
print "Enter a date YYYY MM DD. Remember perl's months go from 0-11.\n";
while (@dateEnt < 1) {
    my $dateEntered = <STDIN>;
    chomp $dateEntered;
    push @dateEnt, $dateEntered;

    (@datedata) = split (/\s+/, $dateEntered);
    $year= $datedata[0];
    $month = $datedata[1]; 
    $day = $datedata[2]; 
}

$time = time; 
$readabletime = localtime($time); 

use Time::Local; 
$timeEntUseable = timelocal(00, 00, 00, $day, $month, $year);  
$laterdate = localtime($timeEntUseable + (60 * 60 * 4 * 24)); 
print "The time 7 days and 4 hours from the time entered is $laterdate\n";
```

When I enter 2015 00 01 (Jan 1, 2015) into the first question my result is Jan 2, 2015 at 4:00:00. The answer should be Jan 7, 2015 at 4:00:00. Any help?

Answer (score 6):

Using Time::Piece and Time::Seconds (core since 5.10):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $date;
until ($date) {
    print 'Enter a date (YYYY/MM/DD): ';
    chomp(my $input = <>);
    $date = eval { 'Time::Piece'->strptime($input, '%Y/%m/%d') };
}
$date += 7 * ONE_DAY + 4 * ONE_HOUR;
print $date, "\n";
```

Note that the result is Thu Jan  **8** 04:00:00 2015, as `1 + 7 = 8`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `eval` here? Can we not call `Time::Pice->strptime` directly?

Comment: @skmrx: It handles incorrect input, like "today", "qwerty", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think here:

```
$laterdate = localtime($timeEntUseable + (60 * 60 * 4 * 24));
```

should be:

```
$laterdate = localtime($timeEntUseable + (60 * 60 * (24 * 7 + 4)));
```

And isn't the correct output Jan 8, 2015 at 4:00:00?

- `60 * 60` means an hour
- `24 * 7` means hours of 7 days
- `+ 4` means additional 4 hours to that of 7 days